# DSpace 4.x: Error while package building with Maven

Tags: maven, dspace

I'm trying to install DSpace 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm getting a constant error while attempting to build the installation package with Maven (using `mvn package`), which is:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.dspace:dspace:4.1
          (/home/dspace/dspace-4.1-release/dspace/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.dspace:dspace-parent:4.1:
            Failure to find org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:7 in
            http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in
            the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
            update interval of sonatype-releases has elapsed or updates are
            forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @
            org.dspace:dspace-parent:4.1, /home/dspace/dspace-4.1-release/pom.xml,
            line 20, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
        the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I've tried defining a proxy for Maven, I've tried having no proxy for Maven. I tried with both DSpace 4.2 and 4.1. Running `mvn clean` gets the same error.
I checked the sonatype repository and seemingly the release mentioned by the pom.xml doesn't exist (I didn't make any change to the pom.xml file).

Software info:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).
- DSpace 4.1, binary release (I've tried with 4.2, binary release, too, but still getting the same error).
- Apache Maven 3.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `mvn package` in root folder `/home/dspace/dspace-4.1-release/` and not in `/home/dspace/dspace-4.1-release/dspace`